# How to save a webpage

Tags: html

I'm on a website which has multiple links, but when I click a new link, it just changes the screen, not the url. I'm trying to save the screen, but it is saving the original screen. I right click, save as, webpage, complete or webpage, html only (I've tried both), but the original screen shows when I open the file. Any way to get the screen that I want? The one in which I clicked the link.

Comment: 'Save As' will make a request to the current URL, which would be the original page. You'll have to copy/paste the content, do a screen print, or find some plug-in to handle that.

Comment: Could you give us any indication as to how the routing of the page in question works? Also, what type of content do you actually want to save? (Like, do you want the HTML files, or just the content?)

Answer (score -2):

I have to assume that the links are javascript or php connected and are echoing a new html code when you click the link. The echo once clicked should change the source output to your browser. Try to right click on the page after you clicked the link and select view source, or inspect element and see if you can find these links targets' or copy paste the renewed browser code to your browser into a notepad document then save the file as a .html save to your desktop and open. That should create the same screen you see when you click a link.

click the link, view the change you want to save. right click and select "view source" copy the source and paste into notepad. Save as a.html file and run with a browser. this should produce the visual are looking for then print.